# Python: tell my IDE what type an object is

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, spyder

When I write a function in Python (v2.7), I very often have a type in mind for one of the arguments. I'm working with the unbelievably brilliant `pandas` library at the movemement, so my arguments are often 'intended' to be `pandas.DataFrame`s.

In my favorite IDE (Spyder), when you type a period `.` a list of methods appear. Also, when you type the opening parenthesis of a method, the docstring appears in a little window.

But for these things to work, the IDE has to know what type a variable is. But of course, it never does. Am I missing something obvious about how to write Pythonic code (I've read [Python Is Not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) but it doesn't mention this IDE autocomplete issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know if it works in Spyder, but many completion engines (e.g. Jedi) also support assertions to tell them what type a variable is. For example:

```
def foo(param):
    assert isinstance(param, str)
    # now param will be considered a str
    param.|capitalize
           center
           count
           decode
           ...
```

Comment: Works in PyCharm

Comment: Works like a charm in CLion too! (it is using the same engine as PyCharm, BTW)

Answer (score 10):

Actually I use **IntelliJ idea ( aka pyCharm )** and they offer multiple ways to specify variable types:

**1. Specify Simple Variable**

Very simple: Just add a comment with the type information behind the definition. From now on Pycharm supports autcompletition! e.g.:

```
def route():
    json = request.get_json() # type: dict
```

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

**2. Specify Parameter**:

Add three quote signs after the beginning of a method and the idea will autocomplete a docstring, as in the following example:

[image: example of method parameters]

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html

(Currently on my mobile, going to make it pretty later)

Comment: The second option is the cleanest and easiest in my opinion. You have to use it only once in a class and store it in a field and you are good to go, while with 'assert isinstance' you have to use it in every method.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 3, you can use [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). As an example:

```
@typechecked
def greet(name: str, age: int) -> str:
    print("Hello {0}, you are {1} years old".format(name, age))
```

I don't use Spyder, but I would assume there's a way for it to read the annotations and act appropriately.

Comment: Oops. Should've specified Python 2.7.1. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether Spyder reads docstrings, but PyDev does:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

So you can document the expected type in the docstring, e.g. as in:

```
def test(arg):
    'type arg: str'
    arg.<hit tab>
```

And you'll get the according string tab completion.

Similarly you can document the return-type of your functions, so that you can get tab-completion on `foo` for `foo = someFunction()`.

At the same time, docstrings make auto-generated documention much more helpful.

Comment: Gosh. Spyder people, can Spyder do this? (My early experimentations suggest not, but I wouldn't like to write it off!)

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @LondonRob Sorry, we don't support that. We are limited to the functionality provided by the code completion library we use (which is called `rope`). Maybe this is implemented in a new library called `jedi` (support for which is going to arrive soon) but I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the dynamic features of Python, I use Spyder and I've used a lot more of python IDEs (PyCharm, IDLE, WingIDE, PyDev, ...) and ALL of them have the problem you stated here. So, when I want code completion for help I just instantiate the variable to the type I want and then type ".", for example: suppose you know your var `df` will be a `DataFrame` in some piece of code, you can do this `df = DataFrame()` and for now on the code completion should work for you just do not forget to delete (or comment) the line `df = DataFrame()` when you finish editing the code.